# How to use slice JS in array

Tags: javascript, slice

I have this array

```
 {product.images.map((img, index) => (
                        <img key={index} src={img.url}
                        
                         />
                    ))}
```

as I only wanna render first 5 photos..
How to get the first 5 photos from an array ??

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Really, you could google this and get your answer in 5 seconds. There's no point creating a Stackoverflow question for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
{ product.images.slice(0, 5).map((img, index) => (
    <img key={index} src={img.url}/>
)) }
```